# Apiko - trying to update an existing file

Tags: apiko

With the Quasar Framework has created a form to add and update files on the server Apiko.

With this code trying to update a file that already exists on the server Apiko - https://gist.github.com/gearmobile/cc7de273d9c526b589e198eb35ff89d6

However the update file on the server Apiko fails, and the browser console there are no errors.

Console Apiko gives this log:

```
...
[APIKO LOG 11:34:25.093] Checking if a different session token is specified...
[APIKO LOG 11:34:25.093] No session token is specified, going with luYzmm9Dgzte2OKcLvIyN2b4K5c8Ijeu
[APIKO LOG 11:34:25.094] Checking restrictions...
[APIKO LOG 11:34:25.094] This request has passed the restrictions check.
[APIKO LOG 11:34:25.094] Checking parameters...
[APIKO LOG 11:34:25.094] This request has passed the params check.
```

Help to understand, what is the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `PUT /files/:id` endpoint, which is not implemented in Apiko by default. The reason is that normally to update files you can instead delete an existing one (`DELETE /files/:id`) and upload a new file (`POST /files`).

Alternatively, you can create a custom endpoint that would override `PUT /files/:id` to handle file updates for you.

If you would like to see this feature in Apiko's core, please go ahead and [vote here](https://github.com/apiko-rest-api/apiko/issues/81).

Comment: therefore, if I want to make an app which will only use the basic features Apiko, I need to exclude this page from my project?